# Implementing Trace Geometric Network into Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geometric-network, trace

I would like to use Trace Geometric Network in model builder with the option to have a model parameter for the flags (like the flags I add from Utility Network Analyst Toolbar) and return the results as a selection set.

Answer (score 3):

You can not set a flag as a model (or gp tool) parameter. However, you can use a point feature class instead of a set of flags. Therefore if you select some features of that point feature class the tool will just take those selected ones to the account.

So, use [**"Trace Geometric Network"**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/geometric-networks/trace-geometric-network-using-geoprocessing.htm) geoprocessing tool with your model and set the **Flags** parameter with your point feature layer. This tool returns the result as a selection set.

Answer (score 2):

i was able to do this. I added Trace Geometric Network tool to model builder. I set the Flags and Barriers as Feature Sets (also make these Model Parameters) and imported a symbology from my map (important so Coord sys is the same). Then use the Snap tool to snap the Flags and Barriers to lines or devices. I then used Select Data to choose from the trace results and used the Make Feature Layer to create the selection add it to the map. You must make this result a MP and Add to Display.
Use your map service as a base map so it projects correctly.

Esri has a good example: http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/gp-service-example-geometric-network-trace.htm